# Progress Dialog in OnPreExexcute() not working

Tags: android

I am newbie to android and facing issue on Progress dialog,though myriad question and answers are here but none is working for me.Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I want to show a spinning wheel on my login page of app,all my Async Task activties are in different class and I am passing the activity reference to my HttpClientHelper class which is handling Async Task.No progress dialog appears when i click on Login button. 
Most of the answers have mentioned to implement the Async Task in Activity class but i have created a utility class which is handling the POST/GET in background.
Hence in thin non activity class i dont have the reference of Context so i passed LoginActivity.this in HttpClientHelper constructor.
AM i doing something wrong here.Due to multiple use of POST/Get i can implement them in each activity.
 Please find the sample files these are not actual code I am posting the steps

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     HttpClientHelper httpClientHelper = new HttpClientHelper(LoginActivity.this);
     JSONObject json = httpClientHelper.postJSON(apiURL
                            , params);

    ...... rest of the code

  }

}
```

Here is the HttpClientHelper

```
public class HttpClientHelper {

    private Activity activity;
    private static HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    private static String result;
    private static JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    public HttpClientHelper(){

    }
   public HttpClientHelper(Activity activity){
       this.activity=activity;
   }

 public JSONObject postJSON(String url, Map<String, String> params) {
        Params param = new Params(url, params);
        PostAsyncTask myTask = new PostAsyncTask();
        try {
            jsonObject = myTask.execute(param).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

private class PostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Params, String, JSONObject> {
        JSONObject json = null;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public PostAsyncTask(){

        }
        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Login");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading..Please Wait");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Params... args) {

            json = HttpClientHelper.getJSONFromURL(args[0].url, args[0].params);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            super.onPostExecute(json);
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {   
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously, because `AsyncTask.get()` makes this call synchrous again ...

Comment: Selvin are you talking of myTask.execute(param).get()? This code is working fine only issue is progress dialog is not appearing.No issues with get().

Comment: more explanations: most of UI framework base on message queue ... the mesages are dispatched on single thread(UI thread) ... one of the most important message is redraw/draw/WM_PAINT which draw the UI ... if you block the execution in this thread othere messages will not be executed ... you block the UI thread in onClick ) ... so there is no redraw in the middle of onClick's execution ...   and as you show there dialog and hide there the dialog will not appear

Comment: *This code is working fine only issue is progress dialog is not appearing* lol ... it is not working fine ... it is why dialog is not showing

Comment: Can you add Log in onPreExecute?

Comment: what for ... it is obviously get called ...

Comment: i replaced the code with  jsonObject = myTask.execute(param).get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); and now dialog comes up but with some time lag.It is not displaying the Toast text in first attempt though showing second time.

Comment: Remove the .get() so you use the async task async. Example of bad coding using .get(). Redesing the flow of your program. It will become better.

Comment: Thanks Greenapps. I revised the code now myTask.execute(param);but it is crashing frequently.Earlier it was not crashing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Progress dialogue is associated with UI and any updates in view is not recommended to put inside a AsyncTask. UI updates or changes should occur in the UI thread. 
In your case, the desired result can be achieved by setting a listener to the AsyncTask. Simply add a listener class and implement the listener in the activity class.

Here's an example. 
HttpResponseListener.java

```
public interface HttpResponseListener {
    public void httpResponseReceiver(String result);
}
```

Now in your LoginActivity implement the interface like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HttpResponseListener {

    // rest of your code
    // initialize your progress dialogue here and execute the asynctask
    progressDialogue.show();
    myTask.execute();
    myTask.mHttpResponseListener = this;

    @Override
    public void httpResponseReceiver(String result) {
        if(result == null)progressDialogue.dismiss();
        else {
            // Use result to serve your purpose
            progressDialogue.dismiss();
        }   
    }
}
```

Now in your AsyncTask class, set the result in post execute.

```
private class PostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Params, String, JSONObject> {
    JSONObject json = null;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public HttpResponseListener mHttpResponseListener;

    public PostAsyncTask(){

    }

    @Override
    protected  void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Params... args) {

        json = HttpClientHelper.getJSONFromURL(args[0].url, args[0].params);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        mHttpResponseListener.httpResponseReceiver("OK");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mHttpResponseListener.httpResponseReceiver(null);
    }
}
```